# A result on semisimple left Artinian Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, artinian

We would like to prove the following result.

> ***Theorem.*** Let $R$ be a semisimple left Artinian ring. Then, every non-zero left ideal $J$ of $R$ can be written as a direct sum of
>   finitely many minimal ideals.

We can use the following results:

(1) Every non-zero left ideal of an Artinian Ring $R$, contains a minimal left ideal.

(2) If $I$ is a minimal left ideal of $R$, then either $I^2=\{ 0_R \}$ or there exists an idempotent element  $e\in R$ such that $I=Re=Ie$.

(3) If $e\in R$ is an idempotent element of $R$, then $R=Re\oplus R(1_R-e)$.

In the proof in my notes, I find the first line confusing. It says that *assume that the result fails, ie assume that $J$ is a left ideal, not a direct sum of minimal ideals but any left ideal $J'\subsetneqq J$ is a direct sum of minimal ideals.*

So,

1. Could you please explain why and how do we take this assumption?
2. Could you please write down clearly the proof using the facts above?

Note that we say that $R$ is semisimple left Artinian, if it is left Artinian with nilradical $N(R)=\{0_R\}$ (where $N(R)$ is defined as the sum of all nilpotent ideals of $R$).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

$$\mathcal{F}=\{I\subseteq R|\,I\mbox{ is a left ideal in }R\mbox{ and }I\mbox{ is not a direct sum of minimal left ideals of }R\}$$

Assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is nonempty (if it is empty, then we are done). Since $R$ is left artinian, there exists a minimal (with respect to inclusion) ideal $I\in \mathcal{F}$. Then $I$ is a left ideal and not a direct sum of minimal left ideals of $R$. Note that for every left ideal $J\nsubseteq I$ by minimality of $I$ we deduce that $J$ is a direct sum of minimal left ideals. This justifies the claim from your note.

Next consider $I$. Then there exists minimal left ideal $I_0\subseteq I$. We cannot have $I_0^2 = 0$ because $N(R) =0$. Thus $I_0 = Re$ is generated by an idempotent $e$. Next $R = Re\oplus R(1-e)$ as left $R$-module. We have 
$$I = I \cap (Re+R(1-e)) = I\cap (I_0 + R(1-e)) = I_0 + I\cap R(1-e)$$
and also $I_0 \cap (I\cap R(1-e)) = Re\cap (I\cap R(1-e)) = 0$. This implies that
$$I = I_0\oplus (I\cap R(1-e))$$
as left $R$-modules. Then $J = (I\cap R(1-e))$ is a left ideal properly contained in $I$. Then $J$ is a direct sum of minimal ideals by assumptions. We derive that $I$ is a direct sum of minimal left ideals. This is contradiction. Thus $\mathcal{F}$ is empty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain why $Re \cap (I\cap R(1-e))=0$? Is it because $Re\cap R (1-e)=0$?

Comment: @Chris Yes. This is precisely the reason.

Comment: Excellent. Many thanks.